add_global_p with robust standard errors
I'm fitting a modified Poisson regression model to my binary outcome data. I've managed to use tidy_robust to estimate and use robust standard errors for each level.
In the minimal reprex below, the rse model shows the robust standard errors. When I try and add the global p-value to the table output, see that the global p-value is not calculated from the robust standard errors, but from the original model.
However, I'm struggling to know how to use these robust standard errors when reporting the global p-value for each predictor. Could anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks for any help!!
mod <- glm(
  vs ~ factor(am),
  data = mtcars,
  family = poisson(link = "log")
)

rse <- lmtest::coeftest(mod,
  vcov = sandwich::vcovHC(mod,
    type = "HC1", save = TRUE
  )
)

# model without robust standard errors
mod |> broom::tidy()

# model with robust standard errors - note that they're slightly smaller
rse |> broom::tidy()

gtsummary::tbl_regression(
  mod,
  exponentiate = TRUE,
  tidy_fun = function(x, ...) gtsummary::tidy_robust(x, vcov = "HC1", ...),
) |> 
  gtsummary::add_global_p(keep = TRUE)


